# why am I getting an empty arraylist in Kotlin Fragment?

Tags: android, variables, android-fragments, kotlin, arraylist

I have fragment and an Array List I am trying to add values to this Array List inside a function.  When I print it inside the function, it works. But, when I try to print it outside the function Array List comes empty.

I can see that I am missing a logic here.

Can anyone help me where am I doing wrong?

here is the Fragment file.

```
class HourlySalesFragment : Fragment() {

val tt = arrayListOf<Double>()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {

 //some other code here.

 val valueEventListener08_30 = object : ValueEventListener {


        var subtotalList = arrayListOf<Double>()


        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                for(ds in p0.children) {
                    println("data snapshot "+ds)

                    val subtotal = ds.child("subTotal").getValue(Double::class.java)!!

                    subtotalList.add(subtotal)
                    textSubTotal8_30.text = subtotalList.sum().toString()

                }

                tt.add(subtotalList.sum())
                println("ttt 8:30 "+tt)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    }
    println("ttt outside"+tt)
```

and this is the result I am getting.

```
ttt outside[]
ttt 8:30 [5.0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outside print get called before `onDataChange` callback and so `tt` is empty at that moment. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to fill up an arraylist inside `onDataChange` and fetch those values outside `onDataChange` so that I can use it for another purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your println("ttt outside"+tt) statement is executed first, before asynchronous method completes its execution.

```
val valueEventListener08_30 = object : ValueEventListener {


        var subtotalList = arrayListOf<Double>()


        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                for(ds in p0.children) {
                    println("data snapshot "+ds)

                    val subtotal = ds.child("subTotal").getValue(Double::class.java)!!

                    subtotalList.add(subtotal)
                    textSubTotal8_30.text = subtotalList.sum().toString()

                }

                tt.add(subtotalList.sum())
                println("ttt 8:30 "+tt)
                useArray()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    }




   fun useArray(){
        println("ttt outside"+tt)

    }
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. Is there any way that I can fetch those `tt` values?

Comment: Yes, you can use that array list value only after onDataChange() method completes its execution, that is at last statement of that method.

Comment: thanks, how about if I like to fetch those values outside of  `ValueEventListener`?

Comment: If you want to use that array in other method  outside of ValueEventListener, then you have to call that method, after asynchronous method completes its execution. That is how asynchronous methods works, otherwise you will not get updated data, see my updated answer for this.

Comment: Thanks Nehal. But here is the issue its giving now. `unresolved reference: useArray` I have moved the `useArray()` function to before `valueeventlistener `and now it works. Thanks a million.

Comment: Its just a demo method I created for your reference, and it is already there in my answer